# Removing remote branch pushed to wrong repository

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

By mistake I have pushed a commit into wrong repository 'B' instead 'A' (it was wrong repository path in repository's settings). After that the repository 'B' contains its branches plus new all branches from repository 'A'. New branches do not intersect with existing branches (like detached, or just like two separated trees). How to remove new remote branches from repository 'B' and to make the history of mistake branches hidden? All actions were made thru SourceTree (commit&push).

Comment: [old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2003515/5781248)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to `git push originB --delete <newBranchName>` to delete the new branch on originB?

Comment: I have fixed by deleting the remote branch thru local menu on the remote branch. I guess it same as `git push origin :<branch_name>`

Answer (score 0):

Just have deleted the remote branch by local menu on branch name.